# Why is there a change in inequality from ">" to "$\geq$" in this example?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I copied the example out but I am not interested in the example per say, except for the change in inequality that takes place. I underlined it in red.

**The Example**

[image]

**My Question**

What I understand: (for RHS)

$f(x) - g(x) < \frac{f(p)}{2}$

$\implies g(x) >f(x) - \frac{f(p)}{2}$

so how did get "$\geq$"?

Comment: Surely $A > B$ implies $A \geq B.$ I don't see any particular reason why it's not "$>$" in the second underlined inequality, but writing $\geq$ doesn't spoil the proof.

Comment: @DavidK, thank you for your reply. But shouldn't $A > B$ mean that $A$ never actually  $= B$, but $A \geq B$ implies that $A$ can  $= B$. Allowing this feels like room for some misplay, or am I not fully understanding what "$A > B$" really means?

Comment: I see there is a full answer now, so I don't need to explain. But for what it's worth, I think $>$ would have been preferable to $\geq$. It just happens that the proof still holds up, but it introduces an extraneous "or $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{f(p)}{2}$" which we know has no effect since $g(x)\neq f(x)-\frac{f(p)}{2}$, and the proof would be cleaner if this extraneous "or" weren't there.

Comment: If "Adam is an anteater" is true, then "Adam is an anteater or a zebra" is also true.  "Adam is an anteater" is a *stronger* statement because it is telling you that Adam is most assuredly and anteater and the second is only telling you that "Adam is either an anteater or a zebra".  But a weaker statement is *still* a true statement...  After all if it were *not* true that $A \ge B$ it what have to be true that $A < B$ and that is WRONG.  So $A \ge B$ ***is*** true.

Comment: Actually, I bet that was just a type-setting error that never was caught.  I bet the manuscript *did* say $g(x) > f(x) - \frac {f(p)}2$.  (But what is written is not technically wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider two numbers $x$ and $y$. Then $x\geq y$ implies either $x=y$ OR $x>y$ holds.
So, if $x>y$ is **true** then so is $x\geq y$ since $x\geq y$ requires *at least one* of $x=y$ OR $x>y$ to be true. Think of it in terms of (mathematical) logic.
Thus, if the statement $g(x)>f(x)-\dfrac{f(p)}{2}$ is **true**, then this **implies** that the statement $g(x)\geq f(x)-\dfrac{f(p)}{2}$ is also automatically **true**.

Comment: For example, it is true to say that $1 \geq 2$, even though it would be a strange thing to say

Comment: @PrinceM Do you mean $1\leq 2$?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in previously submitted answer, logically you can say $x > y$ can also be written as $x ≥ y$ because at least one of the cases is valid. According to this $5 ≥ 2$ also taken as correct. But I think it's better to include equal sign if there is a possibility for it to happen because it is a special case. 
Let's consider an integer $n$, can you say $n > 5$ is same as $n ≥ 5$? I suggest you can't because in the first case minimum of $n$ is $6$, but in the second case minimum of $n$ is $5$, therefore the implications are totally different. 
Let's consider another situation,  
Does it imply $a ≥ c$  given that $a ≥ b > c$ or $a ≥ c$ given that $a ≥ b ≥ c$?